# Azure Data Disk with or without Availability zones

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

```
{
        "condition": "[greater(int(parameters('datadiskGB')),0)]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/disks",
        "apiVersion": "2018-09-30",
        "name":  "[variables('dataDiskName1')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Premium_LRS"
        },
        "zones": ["[if(equals(int(parameters('availabilityZone')),0), '', parameters('availabilityZone'))]"],
        "properties": {
            "creationData": {
                "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('datadiskGB')]"
        }
    }
```

this is for  creating a datadisk based on parameter datadiskGB and availabilityZone . Its part of the generic template and sometimes we don't need availability zone  (value 0) . How to make sure the above code works  for all availability zones values 0,1,2 and 3 ? .

"zones": ["[if(equals(int(parameters('availabilityZone')),0), '', parameters('availabilityZone'))]"],
The above code gives error  - "The zone(s) '' for resource 'Microsoft.Compute/disks/datadisk1' is not supported. The supported zones for location 'westeurope' are '1,2,3'" .
Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- ​By default Azure comes with Availability zone 1,2,3 only & We don't
  have any availability zone 0.
- Availability zones are not supported in
  all the regions it only supports some specific region the below
  document will give you the list of azure regions that support
  [Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-region#azure-regions-with-availability-zones)
- Would suggest you to replace the "zone" logic with the below in the above shared arm template.

```html
"zones": "if(empty(parameters('availabilityZone')),parameters('availabilityZone'),array(parameters('availabilityZone')))]"
```